# What is the point of Pool.apply() in Python if it blocks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand what the point of Pool.apply() is, within a parallelisation module.

My understanding is it is synchronous, and so no parallel processing occurs - but you just get the overhead of running code in separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's not useful for parallelization, but it might have other uses. For example, if by poor life choices, your function has an unholy mess of side effects like changing global variables (probably because you only intended to execute it in a Pool when writing it), running it in a separate process can help with that.

Of course, using it like that is most likely an anti-pattern, so I guess this function only exists for compatibility reasons...